# How do you configure application logging with glassfish?

Tags: logging, glassfish

I'm new to logging and am trying to implement it in a webapplication using glassfish. I have implemented my own loghandler using JDBC, but how am I supposed to configure the system to make use of it? Glassfish own logging confuses me a bit, should I mix my own config with glassfish's config in logging.properties in the domain folder, or is it somehow possible to have a second logging.properties with only my own settings? I have tried adding my handler to the root logger in glassfish config like this:

glassfish/domains/domain1/config/logging.properties:

```
handlers=com.company.myapp.util.JDBCLogHandler, java.util.logging.ConsoleHandler
```

However, my logger

```
private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName());
```

list of handlers is null. How can I add the handler without doing it programmatically? I have not included the code for the loghandler since it does work when I add it programmatically.

Comment: Found any solution on this?

Comment: Haha, this is almost 7 years old, even if I was able to remember the config would be done differently in newer glassfish versions. Regardless, glassfish isn't really recommended to use.

Comment: Even if off-topic, would you mind to say what's your recommendation and a short list of "why"?

Comment: I don't know if its still the case, but glassfish was officially unrecommended for production environments by Oracle - the purpose was more of a reference implementation for Java EE.

I mostly use Spring Boot today that uses a bundled tomcat in a runnable jar - very practical, especially if you don't need to configure a lot of special server settings. Even without spring I'd still use a simple server such as tomcat. 

If I had to use a java EE server, i'd use Wildfly. The reason for avoiding Java EE servers is that they they make upgrading specific library versions very hard.